# onRequestPermissionsResult: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I created test app with overridden lifecycle activity methods to log it. So i tried to post message (handler.post()) with runnable in onRequestPermissionsResult to show dialog fragment. And the result is unclear.

One time this runnable is executed after **onPostResume**, and the second time instantly before **onResume**. To catch this bug, you should request permission several times. See attached application and logs :

**Working test**:
D/LifecycleActivity: Request permission
D/LifecycleActivity: onPause
D/LifecycleActivity: onSaveInstanceState
D/LifecycleActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult
D/LifecycleActivity: onResume
D/LifecycleActivity: onResumeFragments
D/LifecycleActivity: onPostResume
D/LifecycleActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult (posted)
D/LifecycleActivity: display Dialog

**Failed test**:
D/LifecycleActivity: Request permission
D/LifecycleActivity: onPause
D/LifecycleActivity: onSaveInstanceState
D/LifecycleActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult
D/LifecycleActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult (posted)
D/LifecycleActivity: display Dialog
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

The onRequestPermissionResult method code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull 
String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
grantResults);

    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult");

    new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult (posted)");
            displayDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

But i implemented the same logic for onActivityForResult callback, and it works for 100%.

I asked this question on issuetracker.google.com: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37067655. My question is the last in the list, and i attached implemented project to it.

Why does the posting message in onRequestPermissionsResult works the different way?

Comment: No code and no details about the API level, no specific question. Please show a minimal example that reproduces the problem being reported, and make it clear what the exact problem is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve